# Tag someone in a comment by using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I want to tag a friend in a comment that I wrote under a post. I found some examples on the internet and I used @[profile_id:1:profile_name]. However, as far as I understand it is also for tagging someone in a timeline not in a comment. Is it possible to tag someone in a comment by using Graph API?

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: @WizKid then also it is not possible to reply to another reply of a comment because it needs tagging as well right?